# ParseDateTime won't output ODBC literals for SQL Server datetime queries

Tags: coldfusion

After setting up ColdFusion 2021 I found that when ParseDateTime is being used to format a datetime value from SQL Server it won't format the date as an ODBC literal like ColdFusion 2016 does, e.g. `{ts '2021-05-15 13:20:51'}`. Instead it just outputs the value unchanged from the database.

Here is my environment:

```
Coldfusion 2016 Server:
Version: 2016,0,17,325979 
Tomcat Version: 8.5.61.0
Edition: Developer  
Operating System: Windows 7

Coldfusion 2021 Server:
Version: 2021,0,01,325996
Tomcat Version: 9.0.41.0
Edition: Developer  
Operating System: Windows 10
```

The database is SQL Server 2008 R2 and ColdFusion datasource is using the MS SQL Server driver.

An example query:

```
<cfquery name="qryDates">
    select id, expiry_date
    from purchases
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>#ParseDateTime(qryDates.expiry_date)#</cfoutput>
```

Coldfusion 2016 output:

`{ts '2021-05-15 13:20:51'}`

Coldfusion 2021 output:

`2021-05-15 13:20:51.0`

Is there a way to get ParseDateTime to behave the way it does on my CF 2016 and every other CF server I have used in the past? I do not want to have to change the formatting to accomplish this (e.g. `#DateTimeFormat(ParseDateTime(qryDates.expiry_date))#`).

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: ParseDateTime() is used for parsing *strings* into date objects, not for formatting the output of dates. Could you elaborate on why ParseDateTime is needed? Based on the the name, it sounds like "expiry_date" is some sort of `date/time` column, in which case it already contains a date object. If you actually did need odbc format you could try createODBCDateTime() instead, but again .. I'm not sure it's really needed.

Comment: Agreed with @SOS. `ParseDateTime()` is for working with String representations of a date. And if `expiry_date` is a string in your database and not a date-type object, then the database needs to be refactored. Dates as Strings is a _horrible_ way to work with dates.

Comment: @Shawn "expiry_date" is indeed a SQL datetime field.

Comment: @SOS The datetime value from the database is stored as a variable (using cfset) that is later inserted into a different table in the database. The problem is that the unformatted date isn't being accepted by SQL Server. ParseDateTime() was used to format the date as an ODBC literal, which was accepted with CF2016 but isn't with CF2021.

Comment: Sounds like the queries aren't using cfqueryparam. We got lucky non-parameterized queries worked as long as they did, because the implementation returned an odbc formatted string. Now that Adobe's changed that, the old method won't work anymore. So you'll need to change the code. Ideally, by using cfqueryparam in all queries, which improves app security and performance. Depending on what's being transferred, a direct `insert` using a `select` might be a possibility as well. While it should work as well, replacing `ParseDateTime()` with `CreateODBCDateTime()` is the least desirable option.

Comment: @SOS Does cfqueryparam do anything for security on datetime fields? Number fields are all parameterized but not date or string fields.

Comment: @DMcG `cfqueryparam` should probably be used on any field that is being being used in the query filters. String fields are the ones you really need to be careful of, though. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure that `cfqueryparam` would work here though. I think the problem is that you're working with a Java data object that _should_ be essentially the same as a ColdFusion date object, but isn't quite. I think the issue might be the `cfquery` that is doing the ultimate `INSERT` isn't quite sure how to handle the Java date object. `cfqueryparam` may validate that it's a date, but it won't convert it to a proper date. You still might have the same issue.

Comment: @SOS I don't have anything to test it with right now, but will `cfqueryparam` handle the object properly with CF2021? That's kinda what's happened here with the `ParseDateTime` function. It treated the database object the same whether it was CF or Java. But 2021 seems to be doing it a little differently depending on the type of object it is.

Comment: Granted, a CF object is a Java object at its heart, so I'm kinda tilting back to the view that improperly handling a Java date object may have been an oversight in CF `ParseDateTime` for years.

Comment: @SOS Lucee does it all different anyway. :-)  BTW: I hate dates.

Comment: @DMcG - Security can be an issue for any raw value passed into a sql string. Numeric values are easier to hack, but I wouldn't say date strings are 100% safe either. That said, the primary function of cfqueryparam isn't actually security, though it's a great benefit. The primary purpose of bind variables is for query performance. (cont'd)

Comment: Since it sounds like you're already using cfqueryparam anyway, better to use it for *all* of the query parameters - including the dates. There's really no reason to rely on string formats and ParseDateTime, since the query already returns a date object and cfqueryparam should accept it just fine: `<cfqueryparam value="#qry.datetime#" cfsqltype="timestamp">`. The only difference should be that it respects milliseconds, unlike ParseDateTime, as @Shawn said.

Comment: I don't have 2021 installed, but here's a demo of how cfqueryparam can translate the timestamp column without any additional formatting. : https://trycf.com/gist/9b3e5317f7dad62f43b4feb08270e850/acf2021?theme=monokai  (Uses QoQ because db queries aren't supported on trycf.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any way to test my assumptions right now, but I assume you're seeing the side effects of the way `ParseDateTime()` handles a Java object, and the differences of that function between CF2016 and CF2021/18.

Since `expriry_date` is an actual `datetime` object in your database, `cfquery` from the database will give you a sql object instead of just a string that looks like a date. Since it has both `date` and `time` components, I believe that JDBC will send a `java.sql.Timestamp` object back to CF.

The purpose of `ParseDateTime()` is for converting a string to a date object, and even though it *can* "format" a date object, that's not what it's intended for. It's initial assumption is that it's being given a string, and because CF is dynamically typed, it will usually try to implicitly convert a value into the correct type. And since the database value is date-ish, CF will try to make it appropriately look like a string. At least that's the way it was intended to work. And it looks like that is what is happening in <CF2016 and Lucee, and the value is getting a `"{ts..."`.

It appears that CF2021/18 is receiving a `date` *object* and not really doing much with it. It seems to be just passing the Java object *(without the `"{ts..."`)* back out, and when ColdFusion tries to convert it to a string, it's not a ColdFusion timestamp variable so there is no `"{ts..."`.

DEMO CODE:

```
<cfscript>
    /*** CREATE QUERY OBJECT ***/
    theDateQuery = QueryNew("dt","timestamp",[{"dt":createODBCDateTime('2021-04-09 12:01:02.345')}]) ;
    writeDump(theDateQuery);
    
    /*** SET QUERY RESULT TO A VARIABLE ***/
    dobj = theDateQuery.dt[1] ;
    writeOutput("dobj: " & dobj & " ("& getMetadata(dobj).getName() & ")<br>");
    
    /*** CONVERT QUERY VARIABLE TO A STRING ***/
    dstr = theDateQuery.dt[1].toString() ;
    writeOutput("dstr: " & dstr & " ("& getMetadata(dstr).getName() & ")<br>");
    
    /*** PARSEDATETIME OF OBJECT ***/
    x = parseDateTime(dobj) ;
    writeOutput("x: " & x & " ("& getMetadata(x).getName() & ")<br>");
    
    /*** PARSEDATETIME OF STRING ***/
    y = parseDateTime(dstr) ;
    writeOutput("y: " & y & " ("& getMetadata(y).getName() & ")<br>");
</cfscript>
```

**CF 2016 and lower**

https://trycf.com/gist/c9c35dccb04f91cd6c06e4082ed306ca/acf2016?theme=monokai

Your database is giving the ColdFusion query back a Java object, which is going into the `ParseDateTime` function, and CF is doing its magic then giving you back a ColdFusion date  object, which looks like a CF timestamp that is easily coerced into what you want it to display.

> dobj: 2021-04-09 12:01:02.345 (java.sql.Timestamp)
>
> x: {ts '2021-04-09 12:01:02'} (coldfusion.runtime.OleDateTime)

**CF2021** *(and CF2018)*

https://trycf.com/gist/4c9bbc036a63a135962f0912b8591e00/acf2021?theme=monokai  *(trycf link for CF2021 seems to be defaulting to Lucee5, so you'll have to reselect CF2021)*

It looks like the behavior changed slightly in CF2018. I don't know the inner workings of the `ParseDateTime` functions, but I'm assuming that in earlier versions, it would convert the date object to a date string before it converted it into a ColdFusion object on return. As of 2018, it appears that if it receives a Java data object, it recognizes that it's already a date object and just returns it (bypassing a conversion to a ColdFusion date string and then object). This is seems to be more in line with the originally stated behavior. And since the Java timestamp value doesn't have `"{ts..."`, but CF does, it changes the way a string us ultimately created from the function's return value. This is possibly a compatibility bug (since the behavior is subtly different), but I'm not completely sure.

Regardless, it seems to be caused by the simple fact that `ParseDateTime` is being used here for something other than its intended purpose. Just like using `TimeFormat(now(),"yyyy-MMM-dd hh:nn:ss")`. ACF will return a string with the Year and Day masked, even though that's not something that `TimeFormat()` is intended for (*NOTE: Lucee seems to handle it correctly)*. If a function is used in an unexpected manner, it shouldn't be expected to return consistent results in different versions.

And that's where I get kinda iffy on whether it should be a bug or not. In the past, most ColdFusion functions didn't much care if a "date" was a string or an object. It seems that CF2018+ does. Or at least treats them differently.

Ultimately, your code should probably be fixed to use functions the way they were meant to be used. However, I understand that might be a bit much. You might be able to fix your current issue by explicitly converting the query object into a string before you parse it.

```
ParseDateTime(qryDates.expiry_date.toString())
```

One other thing to note is that in CF2016, if your datetime value had a millisecond component, that would be stripped off in your final `ParseDateTime` value. However, in CF2021/18, since the Java value doesn't appear to be changed, the milliseconds component will still be in your return value. `toString()` should also fix that, and you'll get exactly what you had before.

Comment: Small note, the `toString()` code requires a row number. Otherwise, you end up getting the string representation of the column object, instead of the value in row 1.